# Simpy 3: Resources.Resource.request()/.release() WITHOUT 'with...as:'

Tags: python, simulation, simpy

I'm trying to add SimPy simulation to a project I'm working on and I have some confusion about version 3's release/request.

I was able to implement resources using a 'with'-block without trouble but in my situation I want to request/release a resource without using a 'with'-block.

However, I cannot find an example of this using SimPy 3. I read the documentation/source regarding resources but still can't get it quite right. Could someone explain how to properly:

```
...
Request a Resource with the method: 'request()'
...
Release that Resource with the method: 'release()'
...
```

Thanks, and sorry for the bother.

PS: I'm intending to use Resources.resource

Comment: Just read up on what "with" actually does. It just calls routines of the object (i think__enter__ and__close__, but can't remember). And then do something like that. Why do you not want to use "with... As..." though?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to use a resource without a `with` block (and you know you won’t get interrupted), its just:

```
req = resource.request()
yield req
# do stuff
resource.release(req)
```

Comment: Exactly what I was asking. My inexperience with Python-generators made learning SimPy harder than it should have been. Thanks for developing SimPy!

Comment: What about if I have multiple resources that I would like to "clear" after each time unit?  Maybe I'm not formulating this the right way, but I would like my process to consume 2 units of the resource, so I did `req = resource.request()` twice.  However, when I do `resource.release(req)`, regardless of how many times I call this 1 resource still remains in use according to `resource.count`

Answer (score 3):

Using `with` on an object calls `__enter__` when you enter the `with` block, and `__exit__` when you leave. So when you do

```
res = resource.Resource()
with res.request() as req:
  # stuff
```

You're really calling `__enter__` on a Request object, doing `#stuff` then calling `__exit__`:

```
class Request(base.Put):
    def __exit__(self, exc_type, value, traceback):
        super(Request, self).__exit__(exc_type, value, traceback)
        self.resource.release(self)

class Put(Event):  # base.Put
    def __enter__(self):
        return self

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback):
        # If the request has been interrupted, remove it from the queue:
        if not self.triggered:
            self.resource.put_queue.remove(self)
```

So, the `with` block is equivalent to this:

```
res = resource.Resource(...)
req = res.request()
#stuff
if not req.triggered:
   res.put_queue.remove(req)
   res.release(req)
```

However, the `with` block is also making sure that the cleanup code is called no matter what exceptions are thrown during `#stuff`. You'll lose that with the above code.

Comment: You get back the cleanup code using `try:...finally:` but then it might as well just use `with`...

Comment: Thanks, I coded up this example (based on the SimPy website doc.) based on reading your post: https://gist.github.com/ndmacdon/1b43b8f29e66fee7a5e1#file-simpyrequestrelease

Answer (score 0):

It's all outlined in [PEP343](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/);

```
with EXPR as VAR:
        BLOCK
```

becomes:

```
mgr = (EXPR)
exit = type(mgr).__exit__  # Not calling it yet
value = type(mgr).__enter__(mgr)
exc = True
try:
    try:
        VAR = value  # Only if "as VAR" is present
        BLOCK
    except:
        # The exceptional case is handled here
        exc = False
        if not exit(mgr, *sys.exc_info()):
            raise
        # The exception is swallowed if exit() returns true
finally:
    # The normal and non-local-goto cases are handled here
    if exc:
        exit(mgr, None, None, None)
```

This is *exactly* how python uses `with... as...` blocks, but I'm presuming there's some reason you don't want to use these. If that's the case, then you just need the `__enter__` and `__exit__` functions. The way i think of it, is `__enter__` sets everything up, and `__exit__` does all the cleanup.